# What will happen if i dont specify tablespace in Oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a AWS RDS account .The database were created and  the necessary oracle scripts were deployed. While creating tables and indexes, I have not specified any tablespace forcefully. I believe the tablespace is taken care by RDS on default.
 What will happen if i don't specify tablespace manually? what will be the maxsize ? will it create tablespace will small dataspace and will create more tablespace everytime the the maxsize get exhausted? worried if it affects my performance.

The AWS is currently being deployed in production. If it is not a big issue, then i can leave as it is otherwise i would be in serious trouble!! please help me with your suggestions

Note:In traditional Oracle database i used to create tablespace, since there is no physical file location in RDS, i have not specified anything manually

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify tablespace during the object creation then the default tablespace is going to used which is assigned during the user creation. If we omit the default tablespace clause during user creation then the user will database default tablespace.

You can get the information  of default tablespace using the following query.

`select * from database_properties where property_name like 'DEFAULT%TABLESPACE';`.

> what will be the maxsize ?

Maxsize is defined during the tablespace creation.

[Creating Tablespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces002.htm#ADMIN11359)

> will it create tablespace will small dataspace and will create more tablespace every time the maxsize get exhausted?

No, if the space of a tablespace exhausts then we need to increase the size of datafiles or add more datafiles if the one is already reached its max size.

[Tablespaces and Datafiles](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/physical.htm#CNCPT003)

You can still create tablespace in Amazon RDS and can choose your own default tablespace as you do in Oracle outside of Amazon RDS.

> Amazon RDS only supports Oracle Managed Files (OMF) for data files, log files and control files. When creating data files and log files you cannot specify physical file names.

[Creating and Resizing Tablespaces and Data Files in Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.Database.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.CreatingTablespacesAndDatafiles)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the infor. maxsize i have not defined? so what will be the case? Can i create my own tablespace without deleting the existing tablespace, as it is in production.

Comment: MAXSIZE of the tablespace is defined during its creation or can be altered to change it. You can use this query to get max size of all the tablespaces of your database- `select tablespace_name, max_size from dba_tablespaces;`. Yes you can create your own tablespace. Please refer to the documentation I have attached in the answer.

Comment: Yes, i know i can create, but im in the need to know whether to create a new tablespace as the code already deployed inproduction, if i need to create a custom tablespace, i need to start from scratch, so was thinking if i can go with the default tablespace forever? will aws handle it by itself as against the traditonal server, where dba will add manually